# Обнуляется таймер при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-webforms

Здравствуйте, у меня есть страничка с тестом. На прохождение теста дается 2 минуты, например. Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "ответить" не сбрасывалось значение таймера в первоначальное? Поменяла серверный элемент Labeltimer на html тэг, результат все равно сбрасывается при нажатии на кнопку.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   function countdown()
   {
       seconds = document.getElementById("Labeltimer").textContent;

       if (seconds > 0)
       {
           document.getElementById("Labeltimer").textContent = seconds - 1;
           setTimeout("countdown()", 1000);
       }
       if (seconds == 0) {

           alert("Тест провален");
           location.reload();
       }

   } setTimeout("countdown()", 1000);

   </script>
```

Разметка страницы

```
 <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>

</div>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">


        <ContentTemplate>

                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Поддерживает ли asp.net ajax запросы? "></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <asp:ListItem>Да</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Нет</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:CheckBoxList>
                <asp:Label ID="Labelresult" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Button ID="Buttonaswer" runat="server" Text="Answer" OnClick="Buttonaswer_Click" />
                <br />

                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Осталось "></asp:Label>

                 <label id="Labeltimer" >120</label>
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="сек">                  </asp:Label>
                <br />
                <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server">
                </asp:UpdateProgress>

        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

</form>
  </body>
```

Comment: У вас при нажатии на кнопку `Answer` происходит *submit* страницы?

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko, если посмотреть разметку страницы в браузере вот какая кнопка

      <input type="submit" name="Buttonaswer" value="Answer"    id="Buttonaswer" />

Comment: Значит, делается *submit* страницы. Значит, при каждом сабмите надо отправлять на сервер значение `Labeltimer`, а при загрузке передавать его обратно на клиент. В функции `countdown` меняйте не `innerHTML`, а `text`.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko, то есть насколько я понимаю мне нужно в функции обработчика нажатия по кнопке сохранять Labeltimer, мне записать его в сессию?

Comment: Что-то вроде того. Можете легче, использовать не `label`, а `input`. Тогда *asp* сам будет сохранять его в сессию, отправлять на сервер и т.д.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko, то есть мне нужно Label заменить на это <input type="text" id="Labeltimer" value="120" /> ?

Comment: Как один из простых вариантов, попробуйте.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko, я поменяла Label на input, а свойство innerHtml на contentText, оно вообще перестало работать как мне это значение правильно обрабатывать в функции?

Comment: Что значит вообще перестало работать?

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko, в input просто статическое значение, не идет обратный отсчет каждую секунду

Comment: Пожалуйста, не отвечайте в комментариях. Последующим людям, которые будут смотреть Ваш вопрос, будет трудно уследить за тем, что вы делали, что бы решить проблему. Редактируйте Ваш вопрос. Покажите там, что Вы пробовали и с каким результатом.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko, изменила вопрос и добавила то, что изменила в коде

Comment: Я не вижу у вас в вопросе тег `input`, вижу только `<label id="Labeltimer" >120</label>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для сохранения значения между `submit`, необходимо значение секунд передавать на сервер и получать его отбратно.

А именно:

- Имеется элемент **input** на странице, у которого с помощью `javascript` меняется значение **value**.
- При `submit` *asp.net* отправляет значение на сервер.
- При ответе сервера *asp.net* заполняет значение **input** ранее полученным значением.

HTML:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

  <label> Осталось 
    <input id="Labeltimer" readonly="readonly" runat="server" value="120" type="text" />
  </label>
  <input id="Submit1" type="submit" 
    value="Answer" />
</asp:Content>
```

И `javascript`:

```
function countdown() {
    var element =  document.getElementById("MainContent_Labeltimer");
    var seconds = element.value * 1;

    if (seconds > 0) {
        element.value = seconds - 1;
        setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
    }
    if (seconds == 0) {

        alert("Тест провален");
        location.reload();
    }

} 
setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
```

---

Использование **label** вместо **input**.

HTML:

```
<body onload="onLoad()">
    <input id="Labeltimer" readonly="readonly" runat="server" value="120" type="hidden" />
    <label>
        Осталось <span id="spanID"></span>
    </label>
    <input id="Submit1" type="button" value="Answer" onclick="saveValue()" />
</body>
```

И `javascript`:

```
   function countdown() {
        var element = document.getElementById("spanID");
        var seconds = element.innerText * 1;

        if (seconds > 0) {
            element.innerText = seconds - 1;
            setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
        }
        if (seconds == 0) {

            alert("Тест провален");
            location.reload();
        }

    }
    function saveValue() {
        document.getElementById("MainContent_Labeltimer").value = document.getElementById("spanID").innerText;
        document.getElementById("ctl01").submit();
    }
    function onLoad() {
        console.log('load');
        document.getElementById("spanID").innerText = document.getElementById("MainContent_Labeltimer").value;
    }
    setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает. А можно input заменить тэгом Label, чтобы красивее смотрелась страничка?

Comment: Это в принципе возможно. Проблема в том, что поскольку **label** не является элементом, в который можно вводить данные, то `asp.net` автоматически не отправляет его на сервер.